# Query regarding smtp_fallback relay in postfix

Tags: postfix

I have 3 postfix instances in my server. I am trying to configure my server in such a way that, the deffered mails in 1st instance need to be relayed to the 2nd instance. Thereby i can reduce the deferred load in my server. I have read about the smtp_fallback delay in postfix which does exactly my requirement. But i cant find any good tutorials to accomplish it. My another doubt is, Does the 2nd instance need to be with the same IP of the 1st or can it be any other ip?

Comment: You don't need multiple postfix instances, a not really tricky master.conf where enough.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: postfix is practically a hird of nearly-independent daemons interacting which eachother. This daemons are defined in master.cf .  You can multiply these daemons - especially the smtp-listener - and assign them to different ports, with different configuration, but in the single postfix instance. That makes your administering work a lot easier. You can see an example in http://www.howtoforge.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-4788.html . It doesn't help your problem directly, only a simple suggestion (this is because I didn't write an answer).